# WebView android coordinates of image

Tags: android, webview, coordinate

i have webView and loadData with area map. I have coordinates of areas and how to change selection orange rectangle to selection area?

I would like get this effect in me WebView: (selection around area) 
This effect is in WebView android 4.4.2

[image]

in now time i have this effect, rectangle selection around area link:
This selection should be around area (image up)

[image]

How can i do this?

code [pastebin.com/9ddKfgw3](http://pastebin.com/9ddKfgw3)

Comment: Please share the code that you wrote so far that is relevant to understand your problem.

Comment: I have activity and this activity load map in WebView. When click on  area map then shows up oragne rectangle selected. WebView did not allow click on the little area map becouse it selects bigger area as you can see in the picture

code: http://pastebin.com/9ddKfgw3

Comment: This selection should be around the area (first image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this code that maybe helps you
https://github.com/catchthecows/AndroidImageMap

Comment: Thank You, i use javascript and wokr very good.
Me soluition: http://pastebin.com/tSK8EV8k